# How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?

Tags: python, windows, directory

What is the best way to get a list of all files in a directory, sorted by date [created | modified], using python, on a windows machine?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

*Update*: to sort `dirpath`'s entries by modification date in Python 3:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

paths = sorted(Path(dirpath).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

<sub>(put [@Pygirl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772122/4279) here for greater visibility)</sub>

If you already have a list of filenames `files`, then to sort it inplace by creation time on Windows (make sure that list contains absolute path):

```
files.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
```

The list of files you could get, for example, using `glob` as shown in [@Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168424/4279).

---

<sup>old answer</sup>
Here's a more verbose version of [`@Greg Hewgill`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python/168435#168435). It is the most conforming to the question requirements. It makes a distinction between creation and modification dates (at least on Windows).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from stat import S_ISREG, ST_CTIME, ST_MODE
import os, sys, time

# path to the directory (relative or absolute)
dirpath = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else r'.'

# get all entries in the directory w/ stats
entries = (os.path.join(dirpath, fn) for fn in os.listdir(dirpath))
entries = ((os.stat(path), path) for path in entries)

# leave only regular files, insert creation date
entries = ((stat[ST_CTIME], path)
           for stat, path in entries if S_ISREG(stat[ST_MODE]))
#NOTE: on Windows `ST_CTIME` is a creation date 
#  but on Unix it could be something else
#NOTE: use `ST_MTIME` to sort by a modification date
        
for cdate, path in sorted(entries):
    print time.ctime(cdate), os.path.basename(path)
```

Example:

```
$ python stat_creation_date.py
Thu Feb 11 13:31:07 2009 stat_creation_date.py
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm trying to compare two directories cdate with each other. Is there a way to compare the seconds between the two cdates?

Comment: @malcmcmul: `cdate` is a float number of seconds since Epoch.

Comment: This works but the most succinct solution is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4500607/68534

Comment: @jmoz: do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python/168424#comment1735260_168424). The solution you've link is wrong: it doesn't filter regular files. Note: my solution calls `stat` once per dir.entry.

Comment: Forgive me, link provided by Sabastian is even more succinct!  Thank you.

Comment: paths = sorted(Path(directory).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 62, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found

Comment: @LavaSangeetham notice that the answer for the pathlib solution says Python 3, not Python 2.7

Answer (score 203):

I've done this in the past for a Python script to determine the last updated files in a directory:

```
import glob
import os

search_dir = "/mydir/"
# remove anything from the list that is not a file (directories, symlinks)
# thanks to J.F. Sebastion for pointing out that the requirement was a list 
# of files (presumably not including directories)  
files = list(filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(search_dir + "*")))
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

That should do what you're looking for based on file mtime.

**EDIT**: Note that you can also use os.listdir() in place of glob.glob() if desired - the reason I used glob in my original code was that I was wanting to use glob to only search for files with a particular set of file extensions, which glob() was better suited to. To use listdir here's what it would look like:

```
import os

search_dir = "/mydir/"
os.chdir(search_dir)
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(search_dir))
files = [os.path.join(search_dir, f) for f in files] # add path to each file
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

Comment: glob() is nice, but keep in mind that it skips files starting with a period. *nix systems treat such files as hidden (thus omitting them from listings), but in Windows they are normal files.

Comment: These solutions don't exclude dirs from list.

Comment: Your os.listdir solution is missing the os.path.join:

files.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(search_dir,x)), os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(search_dir,y))))

Comment: `files.sort(key=lambda fn: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(search_dir, fn)))`

Comment: `files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(search_dir))`

Comment: Your solution doesn't sort by creation date as OP asks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python/539024#539024

Comment: @J.F. - the question actually asks "date [created | modified]" so mtime is a better choice than ctime.

Comment: @J.F. - thanks for pointing out the "key" param to sort, that was added in Python 2.4 and this code was originally on python 2.3 so I wasn't aware of it at the time. Learn something new every day!

Comment: A mere `files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)` should work (without `lambda`).

Comment: Note: after `os.chdir(search_dir)`, you don't need `os.listdir(search_dir)`; you could use `os.listdir(os.curdir)` instead and therefore you don't need `os.path.join(search_dir, f)` either. You could replace the last 3 lines with this: `files = sorted(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.curdir)), key=os.path.getmtime)`

Comment: In case of a large folder, and if one only wants the last file, there is no more efficient way of doing this, right?

Comment: @FooBar to monitor a folder for new files, you could use the `watchdog` module. To find the file created last in the given directory only once, `max()` + `os.scandir()` or `os.listdir()` is enough. Here's [code example (text in Russian)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044)

Comment: How do I manipulate the time it gives me? For example, I want to look at the files that are older than one week? Is there a way to convert the output from os.path.getmtime(x) to a date?

Comment: the os.chdir() is relevant although I have an absolute path. Welcome to Python!

Comment: you could do `files = [os.path.join(search_dir, f) for f in files if ".txt" in f]` to get only .txt files (example) - to get only files with specific extension

Answer (score 44):

There is an `os.path.getmtime` function that gives the number of seconds since the epoch
and should be faster than `os.stat`.

```
import os 

os.chdir(directory)
sorted(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir('.')), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 27):

Here's my version:

```
def getfiles(dirpath):
    a = [s for s in os.listdir(dirpath)
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, s))]
    a.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, s)))
    return a
```

First, we build a list of the file names. isfile() is used to skip directories; it can be omitted if directories should be included. Then, we sort the list in-place, using the modify date as the key.

Comment: It sorted it by oldest first to newest. When I wanted the 5 newest files I had to do the following `a[-5:]`

Answer (score 22):

Here's a one-liner:

```
import os
import time
from pprint import pprint

pprint([(x[0], time.ctime(x[1].st_ctime)) for x in sorted([(fn, os.stat(fn)) for fn in os.listdir(".")], key = lambda x: x[1].st_ctime)])
```

This calls os.listdir() to get a list of the filenames, then calls os.stat() for each one to get the creation time, then sorts against the creation time.

Note that this method only calls os.stat() once for each file, which will be more efficient than calling it for each comparison in a sort.

Comment: that's hardly pythonic, though it does solve the job (disclaimer: didn't test the code).

Comment: This solution doesn't exclude dirs from list.

Comment: @Constantin: that's true, but a quick [... if stat.S_ISREG(x)] would handle that.

Answer (score 21):

In python 3.5+

```
from pathlib import Path
sorted(Path('.').iterdir(), key=lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime)
```

Comment: for creation date, use `f.stat().st_ctime` instead.

Comment: You should cast the `PosixPath` object into `str` in order to execute String methods.

Comment: Maybe I miunderstand the comment. 
Could you clarify which `str` method? We are sorting on `st_mtime`, not `PosixPath`.

Answer (score 18):

Without changing directory:

```
import os    

path = '/path/to/files/'
name_list = os.listdir(path)
full_list = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in name_list]
time_sorted_list = sorted(full_list, key=os.path.getmtime)

print time_sorted_list

# if you want just the filenames sorted, simply remove the dir from each
sorted_filename_list = [ os.path.basename(i) for i in time_sorted_list]
print sorted_filename_list
```

Answer (score 15):

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

sorted(Path('./').iterdir(), key=lambda t: t.stat().st_mtime)
```

or

```
sorted(Path('./').iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

or

```
sorted(os.scandir('./'), key=lambda t: t.stat().st_mtime)
```

where m time is modified time.

Answer (score 13):

Here's my answer using glob without filter if you want to read files with a certain extension in date order (Python 3).

```
dataset_path='/mydir/'   
files = glob.glob(dataset_path+"/morepath/*.extension")   
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
# *** the shortest and best way ***
# getmtime --> sort by modified time
# getctime --> sort by created time

import glob,os

lst_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
lst_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
print("\n".join(lst_files))
```

Comment: please provide context

Comment: "best" is subjective. Your answer would be better if you explained why you think it's the best way.

Comment: If you want "the best", you certainly don't use glob, as it's really slow.

Answer (score 5):

```
sorted(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir('.')), 
    key=lambda p: os.stat(p).st_mtime)
```

You could use `os.walk('.').next()[-1]` instead of filtering with `os.path.isfile`, but that leaves dead symlinks in the list, and `os.stat` will fail on them.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness with `os.scandir` (2x faster over `pathlib`):

```py
import os
sorted(os.scandir('/tmp/test'), key=lambda d: d.stat().st_mtime)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a basic step for learn:

```
import os, stat, sys
import time

dirpath = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else r'.'

listdir = os.listdir(dirpath)

for i in listdir:
    os.chdir(dirpath)
    data_001 = os.path.realpath(i)
    listdir_stat1 = os.stat(data_001)
    listdir_stat2 = ((os.stat(data_001), data_001))
    print time.ctime(listdir_stat1.st_ctime), data_001
```

Answer (score 1):

Alex Coventry's answer will produce an exception if the file is a symlink to an unexistent file, the following code corrects that answer:

```
import time
import datetime
sorted(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir('.')), 
    key=lambda p: os.path.exists(p) and os.stat(p).st_mtime or time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())
```

When the file doesn't exist, now() is used, and the symlink will go at the very end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

This was my version:

```
import os

folder_path = r'D:\Movies\extra\new\dramas' # your path
os.chdir(folder_path) # make the path active
x = sorted(os.listdir(), key=os.path.getctime)  # sorted using creation time

folder = 0

for folder in range(len(x)):
    print(x[folder]) # print all the foldername inside the folder_path
    folder = +1
```

Comment: In my code the files are sorted as oldest to newest. To get newest filenames or folders first, you need to add reverse = True  in the file list (in my case it was x).
so,
x = sorted(os.listdir(), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple couple lines that looks for extention as well as provides a sort option

```
def get_sorted_files(src_dir, regex_ext='*', sort_reverse=False): 
    files_to_evaluate = [os.path.join(src_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(src_dir) if re.search(r'.*\.({})$'.format(regex_ext), f)]
    files_to_evaluate.sort(key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=sort_reverse)
    return files_to_evaluate
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the file directory/folder in path, if you want to have specific file type add the file extension, and then get file name in chronological order.
This works for me.

```
import glob, os
from pathlib import Path
path = os.path.expanduser(file_location+"/"+date_file)  
os.chdir(path)    
saved_file=glob.glob('*.xlsx')
saved_file.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)

print(saved_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out `os.listdir` sorts by last modified but in reverse so you can do:

```
import os
last_modified=os.listdir()[::-1]
```

Comment: "Turns out os.listdir sorts by last modified but in reverse " - No, it doesn't. The doc clearly states: "os.listdir(path='.') Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is **in arbitrary order**" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score -5):

Maybe you should use shell commands. In Unix/Linux, find piped with sort will probably be able to do what you want.