# python have glob return only the 5 most recent file matches

Tags: python, linux, glob

I'm a python newb so please be gentle..

I'm using glob to gather a list of files that match a specific pattern

```
for name in glob.glob('/home/myfiles/*_customer_records_2323_*.zip')
print '\t', name
```

The output is then something like

```
/home/myfiles/20130110_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130102_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130101_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130103_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130104_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130105_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130107_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130106_customer_records_2323_something.zip
```

But I would like the output to be only the newest 5 files only (via the timestap or the os reported creation time)

```
/home/myfiles/20130106_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130107_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130108_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130109_customer_records_2323_something.zip
/home/myfiles/20130110_customer_records_2323_something.zip
```

And Idea on how I can accomplish this? (have the list be sorted and then contain only the newest 5 files?)

UPDATE
Modified to show how output from glob is NOT sorted by default

Comment: See this answer to list files order by timestamps: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4500607/665869

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list-slicing:

```
for name in glob.glob('/home/myfiles/*_customer_records_2323_*.zip')[-5:]:
    print '\t', name
```

EDIT: if `glob` doesn't automatically sort the output, try the following:

```
for name in sorted(glob.glob('/home/myfiles/*_customer_records_2323_*.zip'))[-5:]:
    print '\t', name
```

Comment: thanks I'll test this out, I think it needs one more : after the close ] (I got an error without it)

Comment: Oh, yeah, it does need a colon to open the `for` scope.

Comment: I just tested it and updated the question, glob does not sort output. Sorry for the mislead as my example showed

Comment: mitnk's comment on your original question is a good point. It's probably much more reliable to sort by timestamps than alphabetically, which is what `sorted` does by default (though you can use the `key` parameter to sort however you want).

Answer (score 1):

Slice the output:

```
glob.glob('/home/myfiles/*_customer_records_2323_*.zip')[-5:]
```

I'm not sure if `glob`'s output is guaranteed to be sorted.

Comment: This should give all *except* the last five. The `-5` should come before the `:` as in my answer.

Comment: Good point about not being sure whether `glob` sorts its output, though.

Comment: I just tested it and updated the question, glob does not sort output. Sorry for the mislead as my example showed