# Python Find the most recent file with a specific string in the filename

Tags: python, filenames

In a directory I have lots of files. I want to search the most recent file with "dog" in the name, all extension.

```
path = 'my_path'
name = 'dog'
files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.????(name)])
recent = files[-1]
print "The most recent file with 'dog' in the name is :", recent
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

```
files = sorted((f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.find(name) != -1), 
               key=lambda f: os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime)
recent = files[-1]
```

[`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted) takes an optional argument, `key`, which specifies a function of one argument that returns the key that will be used for sorting. The lambda expression above sorts the array by `mtime` (last modification time). Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500607/2088135) for the lambda.

If you prefer not to use a lambda, you could also just use a normal function:

```
def mtime(f): 
    return os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime

files = sorted((f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.find(name) != -1), key=mtime)
```