# Python: sort files by datetime in more details

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

I using python 2.7 in ubuntu. How do i sort files in more detail order because i had a script that create into numbers of txt flies for split seconds. I had mod a script, it can find the oldest and youngest file but it seem like it just compare with the second but not milliseconds.

My print output:

```
output_04.txt                     06/08/12 12:00:18
output_05.txt                     06/08/12 12:00:18

-----------
oldest: output_05.txt    
youngest: output_05.txt
-----------
```

But the right order of oldest file should be "output_04.txt".
Any expertise know? Thanks!

**Updated**:
Thanks everyone. 
I did try out with all of the codes but seem like can't have the output i need.
Sorry guys, i did appreciated you all. But the example of my files like above have the same time, so if the full-date, hour, min, sec are all the same, it have to compare by millisecond. isn't it? Correct me if im wrong. Thanks everyone! Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible that access information is only store with a resolution of seconds, not milliseconds?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.path.getmtime(path_to_file)` to get the modification time of the file.

One way of ordering the list of files is to create a list of them with `os.listdir` and get the modification time of each one. You would have a list of tuples and you could order it by the second element of the tuple (which would be the modification time).

You also can check the resolution of `os.path.getmtime` with `os.stat_float_times()`. If the latter returns True then `os.path.getmtime` returns a float (this indicates you have more resolution than seconds).

Comment: `files.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, f)))`

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_files(path):
    import os
    if os.path.exists(path):
        os.chdir(path)
        files = (os.listdir(path))
        items = {}
        def get_file_details(f):
            return {f:os.path.getmtime(f)}
        results = [get_file_details(f) for f in files]
        for result in results:
            for key, value in result.items():
                items[key] = value
    return items

v = sorted(get_files(path), key=r.get)
```

`get_files` takes `path` as an argument and if `path` exists, changes current directory to the path and list of files are generated. `get_file_details` yields last modified time for the file.

`get_files` returns a dict with filename as key, modified time as value. Then standard `sorted` is used for sorting the values. `reverse` parameter can be passed to sort ascending or descending.

Comment: how to define that path is exists? sorry, im new to python.

Comment: path = '/home/jack' and then call v = sorted(get_files(path), key=r.get)

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare the milliseconds because there is no such information.

The stat(2) call returns three time_t fields:
- access time
- creation time
- last modification time

time_t is an integer representing the number of seconds (not of milliseconds) elapsed since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC.

So the maximum detail you can have in file time is seconds. I don't know if some filesystem provides more resolution but you'd have to use specific calls in C and then write wrappers in Python to use them.

Answer (score 1):

HI try following code

```
# retrieve the file information from a selected folder
# sort the files by last modified date/time and display in order newest file first
# tested with Python24    vegaseat    21jan2006
import os, glob, time
# use a folder you have ...
root = 'D:\\Zz1\\Cartoons\\' # one specific folder
#root = 'D:\\Zz1\\*'          # all the subfolders too
date_file_list = []
for folder in glob.glob(root):
    print "folder =", folder
    # select the type of file, for instance *.jpg or all files *.*
    for file in glob.glob(folder + '/*.*'):
        # retrieves the stats for the current file as a tuple
        # (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)
        # the tuple element mtime at index 8 is the last-modified-date
        stats = os.stat(file)
        # create tuple (year yyyy, month(1-12), day(1-31), hour(0-23), minute(0-59), second(0-59),
        # weekday(0-6, 0 is monday), Julian day(1-366), daylight flag(-1,0 or 1)) from seconds since epoch
        # note:  this tuple can be sorted properly by date and time
        lastmod_date = time.localtime(stats[8])
        #print image_file, lastmod_date   # test
        # create list of tuples ready for sorting by date
        date_file_tuple = lastmod_date, file
        date_file_list.append(date_file_tuple)

#print date_file_list  # test
date_file_list.sort()
date_file_list.reverse()  # newest mod date now first
print "%-40s %s" % ("filename:", "last modified:")
for file in date_file_list:
    # extract just the filename
    folder, file_name = os.path.split(file[1])
    # convert date tuple to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format
    file_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", file[0])
    print "%-40s %s" % (file_name, file_date)
```

Hope this will help

Thank You