# Conditional for in Python

Tags: python

Does Python have something like below?

```
for item in items #where item>3:
  #.....
```

I mean Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 both together.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can combine the loop with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
for x in (y for y in items if y > 10):
    ....
```

[`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) (py2) / [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (py3) is another option:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

odd = lambda x: x % 2 > 0

for x in filter(odd, items):
    print(x)
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it as no intermediate array is produced. This is called a generator expression. IMO its a pity you cant just write the shorter `for x in items if x>10:` though.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: yeah, that would be neat. This syntax is said to have been rejected by Guido, I haven't found a proof though.

Comment: @georg could you please elaborate in what would be the `itertools.ifilter` usage?

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize you meant the `filter` function, yes, that's more comftible for writing some things. I should probably start paying attention to performance, so far I've settled for making generator expressions as readable as possible, but I until I sit down and measure with clocks I probably won't know if my solutions are "good enough"

Answer (score 12):

You mean something like this: -

```
item_list = [item for item in items if item > 3]
```

Or, you can use `Generator` expression, that will not create a new list, rather returns a generator, which then returns the next element on each iteration using `yield` method: -

```
for item in (item for item in items if item > 3):
    # Do your task
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ah sorry, should have `if` after for.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a special syntax like the `where` in your question, but you could always just use an `if` statement within your `for` loop, like you would in any other language:

```
for item in items:
    if item > 3:
        # Your logic here
```

or a guard clause (again, like any other language):

```
for item in items:
    if not (item > 3): continue

    # Your logic here
```

Both of these boring approaches are almost as succinct and readable as a special syntax for this would be.

Comment: The top-rated solution with a generator expression is more functional and indicates exactly what the list contains on the line of the for expression.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 and Python 2.7 both have `filter()` function which allows extracting items out of a list for which a function (in the example below, that's lambda function) returns `True`:

```
>>> nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> for item in filter(lambda x: x>5,nums):
...     print(item)
... 
6
7
8
```

Omitting function in `filter()` will extract only items that are `True`, as stated in `pydoc filter`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an explicit `if` statement:

```
for item in items:
    if item > 3:
       # ...
```

Or you could create a generator if you need a name to iterate later, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539024/4279):

```
filtered_items = (n for n in items if n > 3)
```

Or you could pass it to a function:

```
total = sum(n for n in items if n > 3)
```

It might be matter of taste but I find a for-loop combined with inlined genexpr such as `for x in (y for y in items if y > 3):` to be ugly compared to the above options.