# python filter files by modified time

Tags: python, logging, time

I have the following code:

```
def filter_by_time(files):
    print "---List of log files to timecheck: "
    for f in files:
        print f, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f))
    print "------"

    mins = datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(raw_input("Age of log files in minutes? ")))
    print "Taking ", mins, "minutes"
    mins = mins.total_seconds()
    current = time.time()
    difftime = current - mins
    print "current time: ", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current)
    print "logs from after: ", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(difftime)   

    for f in files:    
        tLog = os.path.getmtime(f)
        print "checking ", f, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tLog)
        if difftime > tLog:
            print "difftime is bigger than tLog", "removing ", f
            files.remove(f)

    print "*****List of log files after timecheck"
    for f in files:
        print f, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f)) 
    print "******"  
    return files
```

And a sample number of log files. 
The output of the above code when I enter a few minutes is:

```
List of log files to timecheck: 

1copy2.log  11:59:40

1copy3.log  12:13:53

1copy.log  11:59:40

1.log  11:59:40

Age of log files in minutes? 5

Taking  0:05:00 minutes

current time:  2015-07-14 14:02:11.861755

logs from after:  2015-07-14 13:57:11.861755

checking  1 copy 2.log 2015-07-14 11:59:40

difftime is bigger than tLog removing  1copy2.log

checking  1copy.log 2015-07-14 11:59:40

difftime is bigger than tLog removing  1copy.log

List of log files after timecheck



1copy3.log 2015-07-14 12:13:53

1.log 2015-07-14 11:59:40



Collected: 1copy3.log

Collected: 1.log
```

As you can see the files it has collected are not correct. What its doing is checking the 4 files to see if any were modified in the last 5 mins. It removes 2 from the list but should have removed the 4 files.

(Made some edits to make easier to read)

Comment: Consider narrowing down your question, when you're write "as you can see the files" is weird because we don't know what the files actually are and from a glance it's impossible to tell what's wrong. Consider rewriting your question to enhance the issue description and less output.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Comment: related to the old title: to sort files by modificaton date: `files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)`, see [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/168409/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing items from the list while you are iterating the list. The result is unpredictable.

Try iterating over a *copy* of the list like so:

```
for f in files[:]:    # Note the [:] after "files"
    tLog = os.path.getmtime(f)
    print "checking ", f, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tLog)
    if difftime > tLog:
        print "difftime is bigger than tLog", "removing ", f
        files.remove(f)
```

Comment: Thanks using this now. I had implemented the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211209/remove-all-the-elements-that-occur-in-one-list-from-another
But yours is a much more elegant solution

Comment: @pythoner991: `newer_files = [f for f in files if os.path.getmtime(f) >= difftime]`

Answer (score 4):

Consider the `filter` function available in Python. I assume that your input is a list of files and a number of minutes in the past for which you'd like to check, and you want to filter files based for ones that were last modified in the time period between `min` minutes in the past and the present time.

```
import datetime, os
def files_after (files, min)
    lower_time_bound = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=min)
    return filter(lambda f: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(f)) > lower_time_bound, files)
```