# python + run system command with variables

Tags: python, linux, python-2.4

I need to run system command from python

I have python - version - Python 2.4.3

I try the following , in this example **ls -ltr | grep Aug**

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import commands


Month = "Aug"
status,output = commands.getstatusoutput(" ls -ltr | grep Month "  )
print output
```

how to insert the Month variable in the command ?

so grep will do that

```
  | grep Aug
```

I try this also

```
status,output = commands.getstatusoutput( " ls -ltr | grep {} ".format(Month) )
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./stamm.py", line 14, in ?
    status,output = commands.getstatusoutput( " ls -ltr | grep {}     ".format(Month) )
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: `" ls -ltr | grep {} ".format(Month)`?

Comment: see my update , in the question

Comment: *"'str' object has no attribute 'format'"*?! What version of Python are you using? Pre-2.6? You can use `" ls -ltr | grep %s " % Month`, instead.

Comment: Yes, it would have helped to know what python version you are using....

Comment: version on my Linux machine - Python 2.4.3

Comment: @maihabunash you can update that you know

Comment: Is there something stopping you from upgrading to a later version? 2.4 is _ancient_! FWIW, people tell me that I'm behind the times for running 2.6.6 :)

Comment: sorry I cant upgrade this isn't my linux box

Comment: FWIW, parsing the output of `ls` is generally _not_ recommended, although you can get away with it if you know the file names will always be well-behaved. See BashGuide's [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/88378).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import commands


Month = "Aug"
status,output = commands.getstatusoutput(" ls -ltr | grep '" + Month + "'")
print output
```

Or a couple other possibilites are:

```
status,output = commands.getstatusoutput("ls -ltr | grep '%s'" % Month)
```

or

```
status,output = commands.getstatusoutput(" ls -ltr | grep \"" + Month + "\"")
```

Comment: I cant use the import subprocess because my python version    (   File "/usr/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 550, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) )

Comment: You _could_ use single quotes on that grep argument, since it's a fixed string. Double quotes in the shell are needed when you want parameter expansion, but that's not needed here.  Another possibility is `"ls -ltr | grep '%s'" % Month`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the shell, there is `subprocess` module in Python 2.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Month = "Aug"
grep = Popen(['grep', Month], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
ls = Popen(['ls', '-ltr'], stdout=grep.stdin)
output = grep.communicate()[0]
statuses = [ls.wait(), grep.returncode]
```

See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Note: you could implement it in pure Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from datetime import datetime

def month(filename):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename)).month

Aug = 8
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if month(f) == Aug] 
print(files)
```

See also, [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168409/4279)