# Printing out contents of a directory in order of creation date

Tags: python

Has anybody accomplished this with python?

Here's what I have so far...

```
if os.path.isdir(options.map_file_directory):
    searchedfile = glob.glob("*.map")
    files = sorted( searchedfile, key = lambda file: os.path.getctime(file))

    for i in files:
        print("{} - {}".format(i, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(i))) )
```

Comment: *Here's what I have so far* and, does it work? No? What is going wrong?

Comment: clarification... getting no output

Comment: So files is an empty list. I guess `glob.glob("*.map")` is not working correctly

Comment: what in this code are you expecting to make it look at `options.map_file_directory` instead of whatever the current directory happens to be (which could be anything)?

Comment: related: [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/168409/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my own problem. Had to do with the way I was "globbing"

```
if os.path.isdir(options.map_file_directory):
    print ("this is a test 4")
    searchedfile = glob.glob(r'{}\*.map'.format(options.map_file_directory))
    files = sorted( searchedfile, key = lambda file: os.path.getctime(file))

    for i in files:
        print("{} - {}".format(i, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(i))) )
```

Comment: (1) use `files = glob(os.path.join(options.map_file_directory, "*.map"))` (2) you could sort inplace e.g., by modification date: `files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)` (3) [`os.path.getctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) does not (always) return a creation date on POSIX.

Comment: Got an error with (1). Module object isn't callable.

Comment: `from glob import glob`

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to just sort on the time value but also print it out you can store the time in the list you want to sort and spare the second call to getting the time again:

```
import os
from glob import iglob

# ...

if os.path.isdir(options.map_file_directory):
    modification_times_and_filenames = sorted(
        (os.path.getmtime(n), n)
        for n in iglob(os.path.join(options.map_file_directory, '*.map'))
    )
    for modification_time, filename in modification_times_and_filenames:
        print('{0} - {1}'.format(filename, modification_time))
```