# How to list ALL file in a folder (oldest FIRST) using Python

Tags: python

Greeting

I am using Python 3.6 to list ALL file in a specific folder, I am strictly required to list the file sorted by the creation Date/Time in order to process them later based on Date/Time.

I was able to successfully use the following piece of code to list all the required files, interestingly, they came in a SORTED order by Date/Time !!

Does this way ALWAYS GUARANTEE that the files will be list in sorted order ?

Thanks

```
import sys

Source_Path      = 'C:/Myfolder'

for One_File in os.listdir(Source_Path):
    print(One_File)
```

Comment: No, there is no implied order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Comment: it was import sys   ... my mistake

Answer (score 0):

import os

Source_Path      = 'C:/Myfolder'

for One_File in os.listdir(Source_Path):
    print(One_File)

## You, import sys instead of os