# Remove file in the ascending order

Tags: python

In a folder containing , say 5 zip files say we have the following files
123_456_2018_01_01.zip
123_456_2018_01_02.zip
789_456_2018_11_02.zip
789_456_2018_11_12.zip
889_456_2018_11_02.zip

I want to remove the oldest file, i.e  123_456_2018_01_01.zip then 789_456_2018_11_02.zip

how would I accomplish this in Python ?  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Iterate over the files in the directory and sort the file names in ascending order, then delete in whatever way you want.

Comment: Take a look at these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/539024/3287355 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/168435/3287355

Answer (score 0):

If all files have the same pattern, you can use this:

```
import os
list_of_files = os.listdir() # returns list of current directory files
file_to_be_deleted = sorted(list_of_files)[0]
```

Now you have the `name` of the file that should be deleted in `file_to_be_deleted`, then use `os.remove()` to delete the file.

Answer (score -1):

Store your files names in an string array, then sort it

```
array.sort()
```

and use os.remove to remove it

```
for i in array:
    os.remove(i)
```