# Iterating on files named with dates in chronological order

Tags: python

I have a directory containing files named like so:

```
2018-07-14
2018-07-12
2018-07-17
```

Right now I am iterating over all those files like so:

```
from pathlib import Path

def data_generator(my_dir):
    data_path = Path(my_dir)
    for path in data_path.iterdir():
        print(path)
```

Is there a simple to make sure I iterate on the files in order using their name as key, from oldest to most recent?

Comment: using ISO date format lets you sort by date using lexicographic string sorting provided your format (and timezone) are consistent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose `data_path.iterdir()` with a `sorted()` function.

```
from pathlib import Path

def data_generator(my_dir):
    data_path = Path(my_dir)
    for path in sorted(data_path.iterdir()):
        print(path)
```