# How do i read the excel file name from folder(path is constant) when i paste new file then it should read the new file name

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/janardhan.reddy/Desktop/Input/**April**.xlsx")
```

This is my code to read the file from direct path and file name (Jupyter NoteBook)
Q. if i change the file in folder i have to change the file name in path also. So is there any script for to pick the file name directly.(path remains constant)

Comment: Are you asking how to prompt for the file to be selected?

Comment: you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python) to find the newest file to read