# DataLake Files - Last Modified date time

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

Want to get the last updated datetime for the file in datalake using Synapse notebook (pyspark).
Do we have any out of the box options?

Comment: I am using  mssparkutils.fs.ls to get the list of files in the given location. Any leads on getting this list sorted by file modified date will be helpful.

Comment: are you restricted to use Synapse notebook? same can be done using Azure data factory if it's fine for you.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just assign the output to a dataframe and sort that?

```
df = mssparkutils.fs.ls(path)
sorted(df(sortcolumn))
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sort.html

Maybe something like this?
[How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)