# how to get the latest file from folder using python

Tags: python

I have a requirement where I need to process the latest file version when there are multiple versions in a folder. When there are no multiple versions it can process all files.

Example:

```
File1: ABC2021Q1.01.txt
File2: ABC2021Q1.02.txt
File3: ABC2021Q1.03.txt
File4: CDE2021Q2.01.txt
File5: CDE2021Q3.02.txt
```

Files to be processed:

```
File3: ABC2021Q1.03.txt
File4: CDE2021Q2.01.txt
File5: CDE2021Q3.02.txt
```

Comment: Try checking this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Comment: Please post an example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: How many periods can be in these file name? If we split it it on the periods into 3 fields, would that be reliable?

Comment: Is the version just the .02 part or the whole date 202108.02 part?

Comment: version is just .02.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import glob
import os

files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Comment: Should probably be noted that this works so long as the modification time is such that the newest version _always_ is the most recently updated. Otherwise, OP may need something that sorts the files by both modification time and file name (probably reverse-ordered)

Comment: will this pick the latest of all the files from the folder or latest file from multiple files with same filename?

Comment: all i need is to group the files with same name except the version and pick the max version file.

Comment: it will pick the latest of all files from the folder and also if there are multiple files with the same name it will pick the latest version which is recently updated or modified. @Sandysql

Answer (score 0):

data:

```
File1: ABC2021Q1.01.txt 
File2: ABC2021Q1.02.txt 
File3: ABC2020Q1.03.txt 
File4: CDE2021Q2.01.txt 
File5: CDE2020Q3.02.txt
```

code:

```
#encoding=utf-8
import os
import re
def filter_file(path):
    result_dict = {}
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        result = re.fullmatch(r'(.*)(\d{4}Q\d\.\d{2}).txt', file)
        if result:
            name, date = result.groups()
            result_dict[name] = max(result_dict.get(name, '199101.01'), date)
    for name, date in result_dict.items():
        print('{}{}.txt'.format(name, date))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filter_file(r'C:\Users\dqgu')
```

result:

```
ABC2020Q1.03.txt
CDE2021Q2.01.txt
CDE2020Q3.02.txt
```

Comment: i have updated the actual file format , can you look in to it?

Comment: Hi , I have  a below format files  File1: ABC2021Q1.01.txt
File2: ABC2021Q1.02.txt
File3: ABC2020Q1.03.txt
File4: CDE2021Q2.01.txt
File5: CDE2020Q3.02.txt Output: 

File3: ABC2020Q1.03.txt
File4: CDE2021Q2.01.txt
File5: CDE2020Q3.02.txt

Comment: this is not getting my desired output. It is always selecting the max of the list of the files.