# I want to serach some text on multiple files [CLOSED}

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In one directory i have lots of file and in every 4 hours new file named as filename_date is getting created so i just want to check on last 5 created files only. for example

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       5686 Jan 31 06:12 process_list.txt_20220131_061218.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       8921 Jan 31 07:00 process_list.txt_20220131_070001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      13950 Jan 31 08:00 process_list.txt_20220131_080001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      13191 Jan 31 12:00 process_list.txt_20220131_120002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      13093 Jan 31 16:00 process_list.txt_20220131_160002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      13335 Jan 31 20:00 process_list.txt_20220131_200002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      13290 Feb  1 00:00 process_list.txt_20220201_000002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      19205 Feb  1 02:00 process_list.txt_20220201_020001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       9358 Feb  1 04:00 process_list.txt_20220201_040001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      17036 Feb  1 07:00 process_list.txt_20220201_070001.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      17069 Feb  1 08:00 process_list.txt_20220201_080002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      17234 Feb  1 12:00 process_list.txt_20220201_120002.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall  17275 Feb  1 12:00 process_list_previous.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall  17328 Feb  1 12:10 process_list.txt
```

This is list of file in my directory i just want to traverse "process_list.txt", "process_list_previous.txt", "process_list.txt_20220201_120002.txt", "process_list.txt_20220201_080002.txt" and "process_list.txt_20220201_070001.txt"
. Only these files i want to traverse and search something. Is there any module which can help me to restrict number of files need to traverse in python

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Comment: Are you looking to get the last (or first) five elements from a list or are you looking for a way to get a list of files in a folder?

Comment: Basically i want to travarse last five files for example if i want to search 213126 in file
```with open("process_list.txt", "r") as f:
    if '213126' in f.read():
        print("true")``` It will be easy but i want to do same search for these files "process_list.txt", "process_list_previous.txt", "process_list.txt_20220201_120002.txt", "process_list.txt_20220201_080002.txt" and "process_list.txt_20220201_070001.txt" and in next iteration filename should be different.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out this problem and fixed it for now. Adding code snippet

```
files = glob.glob(process_list_file_path)
               # Need to check file is avail or not in files
               if len(files) != 0:
                   files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
                   # If length is equal or less than 5 then 
                   latest=files[-5:]
                   if len(latest) <= 5:
                       print("\n".join(latest))
                       for fn in latest:
                           with open(fn) as k:
                               lines = fn.readlines()
                               for line in lines:
```