# How delete files with condition: files created in "yyyy-mm-dd" at "yyyy-mm-dd" in python?

Tags: python, file, date, operating-system, delete-file

I wanna deleted files in directory, but necessarily created in X date at Y date.
I think used the *library os* but idk how to specify a date condition.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'directory'
dir = os.listdir(path)

for file in dir:
  if file ... in dir:
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get file creation and modification date/times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-do-i-get-file-creation-and-modification-date-times)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last accessed time with `os.path.getatime('/path/to/your/file')`. Also, last modification time (`os.path.getmtime`) and creation time (`os.path.getctime`). More on those [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getatime). But these are in UNIX epoch format. So you should first convert the time you want to UNIX epoch format with the following command:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

# Create the time you want
t = dt(2022, 11, 4, 18, 8, 30)

# Convert to UNIX epoch time
converted = t.timestamp()

# Output: 1667572710.0
```

Now you can check each file's modification/access/creation time and do the comparison, then delete ones you want

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt

# List files in the current directory
list_of_files = os.listdir() 

for f in list_of_files:
    # Creation time
    ct = os.path.getctime(f)

    # Modification time
    mt = os.path.getmtime(f)

    # Check the human readable string
    print(f"file: {f} "
          f"creation: {dt.fromtimestamp(ct)} "
          f"modification: {dt.fromtimestamp(mt)} ")
```

But be careful about converting time-zones! You don't want to give the code a *local time zone* and remove the files based on *UTC*

Some useful resources:

- [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)
- [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- [How do I get file creation and modification date/times?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/6474744)
- [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539024/6474744)