# Rename all file names in your directory using Python and enumerate based on creation

Tags: python

I'm using this code to rename all files in a directory.

```
# Python program to rename all file
# names in your directory
import os, time

os.chdir(r'/Users/al/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/data/mental/tumor/2017')
print(os.getcwd())

for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = "tumor" + str(count)

    new_name = f'{f_name}{f_ext}'
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The code enumerates them in some random order. I would like it to enumerate the files based on the creation or modification date. Is it possible? They include monthly data for a given year, and I have tens of similar folders, so re-sorting them manually is a pain.

Using `enumerate(sorted(os.listdir())):` does not change the behavior.

Comment: You could use `sorted` with `enumerate(sorted(os.listdir())):`

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get a directory listing sorted by creation date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)

Comment: As an aside, you want to use machine-readable stable numbering in the result. Try `"tumor%05i" % count`

Comment: It somehow erased most of the files altogether! I need to re-download it and see if it works. I was too stupid to make a backup before testing.

Comment: Still numers them in a random order for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested in the comments and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/168424/21688300), you need to use `sorted()` and the key by which you want to sort.

By default, if given a list of strings as input, `sorted()` returns the alphabetically sorted list. If you want to use a different sorting criterion, you must specify it.
In this case, you are looking for the functions `os.path.getctime` (for the creation time) and `os.path.getmtime` (for the modification time).

Following code will print the contents of your directory as desired.

```py
import os

print("directory contents listed alphabetically : ")
for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    print(f"{count:03} : {f}")
print()

print("directory contents listed based on creation time : ")
for count, f in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(), key=os.path.getctime)):
    print(f"{count:03} : {f}")
print()

# list based on modification time
print("directory contents listed based on modification time : ")
for count, f in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)):
    print(f"{count:03} : {f}")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

folder_path = '/path/to/folder' 
files = os.listdir(folder_path)
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(folder_path, x)))
for file_name in sorted_files:
    print(file_name)
```